# Read bitmap data going to X server

Tags: 14.04, xorg, video, ffmpeg

I would like to be able to read the data that is being sent to the X server, and stream it into my application for real time processing.  I tried using ffmpeg [2] to capture all the data, but it takes up too much CPU resources, and I don't need to create an mpeg file, I just need to do real time processing.  Also, ffmpeg doesn't capture the mouse. So I was hoping that tapping into X would be much less resource intensive, and that it would capture the mouse.  Another option is to be able to tap into HDMI output.

I am running ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

EDITS:

1. dont need [to create] an mpeg [file].
2. ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 30 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -c:v libx264  capture.mkv
3. [ffmpeg output](https://gist.github.com/mjpuser/b212da7f56d06dc3e0239f79c1675819)

Comment: You should show what you tried: the `ffmpeg` command and the complete console output. You mentioned that you "don't need to create an mpeg", but what output format do you need?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard An uncompressed stream of data would be best, I think.  What I meant by "don't need to create an mpeg" was I don't need to create a file.  I just need something to do real time processing on the data.

Comment: Could you also provide the complete console output from the `ffmpeg` command?

Comment: Added output @LordNeckbeard

Comment: The mouse cursor should be captured by default. I'm not sure why it does not for you. Did you compile `ffmpeg` yourself? Does the file `/usr/include/xcb/shape.h` exist on your system?

Comment: Yes, I compiled ffmpeg myself.  No, there is no /usr/include/xcb/shape.h.  The files in that directory are bigreq.h  xcbext.h  xcb.h  xc_misc.h  xproto.h.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38054/discussion-between-matt-and-lordneckbeard).

Answer (score 1):

## Capturing the mouse

I'm guessing you were missing some XCB dependencies so `ffmpeg` was unable to capture the mouse. You'll need a new `ffmpeg`.

If you want to compile make sure to install the XCB dependencies: `libxcb1-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev`. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Ubuntu Compile Guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) for more details. Alternatively, you could probably use [mc3man's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media) instead of compiling.

## Example command

Your requirements:

- Uncompressed output
- Do not create output file (I'm assuming you want to pipe the output)

This example will output rawvideo in the mpegts format, but you may want to change it to suit your needs. See `ffmpeg -formats` for a list, but note that not all are suitable for piping, such as MOV and MP4.

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 30 -f x11grab -i :0.0 \
-c:v rawvideo -f mpegts -
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm very impressed.  The cpu usage is very low.  Now I need to research these file formats, and how to even play this with ffplay.

Comment: How do I play this stream with ffplay or any video player (assuming I create a file from the above command)?  I'd like to ensure that everything is working properly since when trying to read the data, I'm getting unexpected colors.  I added -pix_fmt rgb24 to make it easy to see the colors by looking at the bytes.  I'm assuming there is just the initial 4 byte mpegts header, and then 3 bytes for each pixel, is that incorrect?

Comment: Looks like ffmpeg doesn't support rawvideo in mpegts.  ffplay won't play it.

Comment: @Matt What is your command?

Comment: `ffmpeg -video_size 100x100 -framerate 10 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -c:v rawvideo -f mpegts -pix_fmt rgb24 video.ts` and `ffplay -f mpegts video.ts`  It could be that ffmpeg is fine, and ffplay doesn't support it, i suppose.

Comment: @Matt You could remove `-f mpegts` and output as `video.nut`. What's your reason for changing the pixel format?

Comment: I want to use RGB because I am trying to emulate something like the human eye, which has RGB detectors (cones).